# Sorting on row totals

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

I am using Excel VBA to pivot some data and use 2 items as rows. I have been able to sort **Column B** (the column with the data - sum/ count). However, I'd also want to sort it in descending order on the basis of row totals. The code I have so far is:

```
pt.PivotFields("LeadStatus").AutoSort Order:=xlDescending, Field:="Count of LeadStatus"
```

Any thoughts?[image: image showing the pivot table I got so far]

Comment: what is "row totals" ? what field Name?

Comment: examples of "row totals" is like cells B18, B21, B24, B27. The cells within that sum up as total. In this case, B21=B22:B23, etc.

Comment: The totals of each group are called subtotal. Row totals would be if you had a `Grand Total` field on the right of the PivotTable like the `Grand Total` field on the bottom of the PivotTable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
For Each pf In pt.RowFields
                  pf.AutoSort xlDescending, pf.SourceName
                Next pf
                For Each pf In pt.ColumnFields
                    pf.AutoSort xlDescending, pf.SourceName
                Next pf
                pt.PivotFields("LeadStatus").AutoSort Order:=xlDescending, Field:="Count of LeadStatus"
```

Comment: The for block sorts the first row condition in the multi level pivot. The pt.PivotFields sorts the second level of row fields in the pivot.

Answer (score 0):

If CurrentSection is the field on which you want to make the second sort, then this might be what you are looking for,

```
pt.PivotFields("CurrentSection").AutoSort Order:=xlDescending, Field:="Count of LeadStatus"
```

Comment: may be i understood your question wrong, if you want to sort `CurrentSection`'s totals and not by its text value then try my updated answer